# Plato's Parmenides conclusion

Tags: plato, parmenides

Reading this http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-parmenides/ and at the end it says that Plato rescues the existence of forms and shows "that Purity-F, Uniqueness, and No Causation by Contraries are all false".. but if those three principles are lost, is there then even the slightest difference between the world of Forms and the world of humans?

Comment: Looking at the paragraph right before section 6 the quoted conclusion sums up the recent non-standard view of Rickless and Gill, the standard view being that Plato's Parmenides only aims to perplex and has no conclusion. The non-standard view sure sounds like reading too much Hegel into Plato with "forms" self-multiplying by moving into their contraries, etc. But for what it's worth Hegel's tale of the Absolute is surely very little like the world of humans, his claims that the rational is the real notwithstanding.